# Disabling interstitial graphic when using cfdiv binding

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

Is there a way to keep the "Loading..." graphic from appearing when cfdiv refreshes?  I'd like to prevent the flicker of loading the graphic then loading the new html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By adding these lines at the bottom of the header, it overwrites the "Loading..." html and seems to prevent the flickering effect in both IE and FireFox:

```
 <script language="JavaScript"> 
 _cf_loadingtexthtml=""; 
 </script>
```

While this seems to do the trick, it would be nice if there was an officially supported way to customize the loading animation on a per page or per control basis.  Hopefully they add support for that in ColdFusion9.

Comment: I agree. Any built-in tag or function that displays anything in the browser should be fully customizable. I was assuming that there would be an extremely easy answer to this question, and was surprised to find the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is currently a way to do this programmatically within the `cfdiv` tag. If you really want to get rid of that "Loading..." message and the image, there are a couple places you can look.

You can rename or delete the image, which is located at:  **CFIDE\scripts\ajax\resources\cf\images\loading.gif**

That only gets rid of the animation. The "Loading..." text can be blanked out to an empty string, and is defined in: **CFIDE\scripts\ajax\messages\cfmessage.js**

Making these changes will obviously have an impact on tags other than `cfdiv`, but if you are looking to eliminate this behavior in one place, I'm sure you won't mind killing it everywhere else too. :)

I'd love to see a cleaner way to do this if anybody else has any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means a comprehensive or an elegant solution, but I found using negative margins on adjacent elements can "cover" the animation. I don't know if this method works in all cases, but for my particular case it worked. The animation appeared next to a binded text field, to the right of which was a submit button. The layer was floated to the right. I used negative margin on the submit button and it covered the animation without affecting the layer alignment.

Another measure I did was to check the layer structure, and added the following code to my css be sure:

```
#TitleNameloadingicon {visibility:hidden;}
#TitleName_cf_button {visibility:hidden;}
#TitleNameautosuggest {background-color:#ffffff;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create functions to change the message prior calling the ajax load that can set the message and image to a new value.

```
function loadingOrder(){
    _cf_loadingtexthtml="Loading Order Form <image src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'>"; 
}

function loadingNavigation(){
    _cf_loadingtexthtml="Loading Menu <image src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading_nav.gif'>"; 
}
```

(these will eventually be rolled into a single function that will take both a text_value and an image_path parameter)

In some of my processes that load both a main and left nav cfdiv I use a function  like this:

```
function locateCreateOrder(){
    loadingOrder();
    ColdFusion.navigate('/functional_areas/orders/orders_actions/cf9_act_orders_index.cfm','main_content');
    loadingNavigation();
    ColdFusion.navigate('/functional_areas/products/products_actions/cf9_products_menu.cfm','left_menu');
}
```